# Materialize CSS Manual Modal Window Size

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I'm working with Material CSS and I want to manually size the modal window if possible. I'm not entirely sure how they're sized...? It seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The default width of modals in Materialize looks like `55%` based on the `.modal` [class](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/47b2f3f8c4b149d4330d554415bc798b889331c8/sass/components/_modal.scss#L11-Lundefined). Since the modal is a block level element and has no explicit height, it will expand vertically to fit its children.

You could manually override the `height` or `width` property of the `.modal` class.